# Display PDF from uri in Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

i'm getting a pdf file from an api, and i got something like that http://x/docs/document1

In my android project, i have like this:

```
try{
   Android.Content.Intent activity = new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(WebViewPDF));
   activity.AddFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
   activity.AddFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
   string uriAndroid = "http://x/docs/document1";
   activity.PutExtra("url", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(uriAndroid));
   StartActivity(activity);
}catch (Exception){
...
}
```

The main problem is, i cannot modify the api, so the endpoint is **http://x/docs/document1**, but if i try another uri, with the .pdf extension, for example **https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf** it works fine.

I don't know if i need to get that info from the API in a different way,
How can i show the pdf in the webView or external app without download first the doc?

Comment: You could use the prefix`https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=xxx`

Comment: tried too, "No preview available"

Comment: Maybe it because of the pdf from the link is unavailable .

Comment: I can see it from Chrome or Firefox, but it's true that you need to set a user and a pass to see it.

Comment: You could add the login info after the url like http://x/docs/document1?userNmae=xxx

Answer (score 0):

The solution was download first and then open from local.

```
        void PrintPdf(Uri uri)
        {

            var webClient = new WebClient();

            webClient.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
            webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Pass");
            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            var bytes = webClient.DownloadData(uri);

            var text = bytes; // get the downloaded text
            string localFilename = "NameforPdf.PDF";
            string localPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).ToString(), localFilename);
            File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, text); // writes to local storage
            bool exists = File.Exists(localPath);
            if (exists)
            {
                Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(localPath);
                file.SetReadable(true);
                //That's the important part, notice the content://
                Android.Net.Uri uriLocal = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://" + localPath);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                intent.SetDataAndType(uriLocal, "application/pdf");
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);

                try
                {
                    StartActivity(intent);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, "pdf reader not installed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }           
        }
```